# How do you prove this involving Gaussian integers?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, quaternions, integer-lattices, gaussian-integers

Q: Show that $\frac{z}{z^2+w^2}\not\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ for all $z,w\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\backslash\{0\}$.

My solution is to consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$$f(a,b,c,d)=|z^2+w^2|^2-|z|^2$$
where $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$, and then to prove $f$ is always greater than $0$.

Is there a more concise or number-theory-like way to prove this? I think it might require the properties of squares of Gaussian integers.

Actually this is a intermediate step in proving the determinant of a quaternion lattice does not depend on the choice of basis. If there is an alternative proof for that I will be more than happy if you could write that down.

Comment: You might want to use the fact that $z^2+w^2$ factors as $(z+iw)(z-iw)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.-In order that $\frac{z}{z^2+w^2}\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ you need that $z^2+w^2$ be invertible. On the other hand, it is well known that the only units (i.e. invertible elements) of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are $\pm1$ and $\pm i$.

It follows you need $$a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2+2(ab+cd)i\in\{1,-1,i,-i\}$$ Since no way to have $2(ab+cd)=\pm1$ it remains to look at $ab+cd=0$ which gives for some integer $k\ne0$ $$(a^2+c^2)(1-k^2)=\pm1\text{ (why?)}$$ It is not hard to see this is impossible in integers.

Comment: Why must $z^2 + w^2$ be invertible?

Comment: If there's a pair $z,w$, choose one such that the norm of $z$ is least. Argue that $\gcd(z,w) = 1$. It follows that for _this_ pair, $z^2+w^2$ is invertible (which fixes Piquito's argument).

Comment: @Piquito: Actually, now that I look more closely, why must $k$ be an integer (as opposed to just rational)?

Comment: Ok, but the gap is fixable: Solve for $k^2$, and note that numerator and denominator of the RHS differ by $1$, hence must both be perfect squares in $\mathbb{Z}$, leading quickly to a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. In stead of showing $z$ and $w$ have no common factor, I think it should be that other cases can be reduced to the relatively prime case.

Comment: @quasi: You have $$\frac{a}{d}=\frac{-c}{b}\iff a=k(-c)\text{ and}\space d=kb$$

Comment: @slade: It is better to say $z+\frac{w^2}{z}$ invertible so equal to $\pm1$ or $\pm i$

Comment: @Piquito: But $k$ need not be an integer.

Comment: @quasi: I think you are wrong. Give me an example with $a,b,c,d$ integers.    Or am I the one who is wrong?

Comment: @Piquito: If $a=6,\;d=9,\;c=-8,\;b=12$, then $k=3/4$.

Comment: @Piquito: As noted in the comments, your outlined proof, in its current form, has a number of flaws. Why don't you edit your answer so as to address the objections?

Comment: @quasi: Thanks you. I rather like to delete my answer (I am in a hurry).

Comment: @Piquito: Your proof strategy is a good one, but it needs more care.

Comment: @quasi: It is not possible to delete because I read "you cannot delete this accepted answer". It is very easy the correction considering common factors in $a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2$. I shall do it after.

Comment: @Piquito: You also need to deal with the question of why you can assume $z^2+w^2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Also, the $k$ in your comment is not the same as the $k$ in your answer. A full, detailed proof would be welcome. No rush.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s try a different strategy from yours, but using the fact that $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a unique factorization domain, and the factorization of the denominator as $(z+iw)(z-iw)$.

We may as well assume that $z$ and $w$ have no common (prime) factor $\pi$, for then we could divide top and bottom by $\pi$ to write our fraction as $\frac1\pi\frac{z'}{{z'}^2+{w'}^2}$, certainly a non(Gaussian)integer if the second fraction is nonintegral.

Under the assumption then that $z$ and $w$ have no common factors (which also excludes the embarrassing possibility that $w=\pm iz\,$), we see that $z$ is also relatively prime to $z+iw$ and $z-iw$, so that the original fraction is definitely reduced.

There’s only one dreadful possibility remaining, that both $z+iw$ and $z-iw$ are units, for instance, maybe $z+iw=1$ and $z-iw=i$. But that possibility gives $2z=1+i$, $z\notin\Bbb Z[i]$. And I confess that I have not run through all sixteen cases, but it seems that all of them yield either $z\notin\Bbb Z[i]$ or $w\notin\Bbb Z[i]$. (There may be a slick way of avoiding that enumeration.)

Comment: Thank you. The idea of considering the case $z$ and $w$ are relatively prime seems to be important in this problem.